# how to preserve my vnc session

Tags: vnc, realvnc

I'm using free RealVNC. I usually connect one of my Linux server with VNCViewer to work with. End of the day, when I disconnect my session, I lost all the running applications in the VNC session.

Could you please let me know to preserve a VNC session for days(or until my remote machine reboots)? Like in mstsc(RDP), I want to connect same session where my applications are running.

Or Do we have any VNC softwares which provide this feature?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the VNC server configured to close the session when the last client disconnects?

Comment: No I did not configure anything.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this thread is quite old, however, there is a solution that I've used for a bit. Using the RealVNC Configuration, once you connect and perform the actions you needed to, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> To lock the desktop and prevent on-premises access to the session you created. from there you can disconnect and close the VNCViewer without worrying about closing the running applications.